# Gorilla/mux middleware not being hit

Tags: go, mux

I am on `go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64`

I am registering middleware, but they don't seem to be hit.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
    "huru/migrations"
    "huru/models"
    "huru/models/person"
    "huru/routes"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func loggingMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {

    log.Println("logging middleware registered");

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Do stuff here
        log.Println("Here is the request URI:",r.RequestURI)
        // Call the next handler, which can be another middleware in the chain, or the final handler.
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

type Exception struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func authMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {

    log.Println("auth middleware registered");

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        params := r.URL.Query()
        fmt.Println("the params are:", params);

        token, _ := jwt.Parse(params["token"][0], func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("there was an error")
            }
            return []byte("secret"), nil
        })
        claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)

        if ! (ok && token.Valid) {
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Exception{Message: "Invalid authorization token"})
            return;
        }

        var user person.Model
        mapstructure.Decode(claims, &user)
        context.Set(r, "logged_in_user", user)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func errorMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {

    log.Println("error handling middleware registered");

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            if err := recover(); err != nil {

                log.Error("Caught error in defer/recover middleware: ", err)
                originalError := err.(struct{ OriginalError error }).OriginalError

                if originalError != nil {
                    log.Error("Original error in defer/recover middleware: ", originalError)
                }

                statusCode := err.(struct{ StatusCode int }).StatusCode

                if statusCode != 0 {
                    w.WriteHeader(statusCode)
                } else {
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                }

                message := err.(struct{ Message string }).Message

                if message == "" {
                    message = "Unknown error message."
                }

                json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(struct {
                    ID string
                }{
                    message,
                })
            }
        }()
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {

    routerParent := mux.NewRouter()
    routerParent.Use(loggingMiddleware)
    routerParent.Use(errorMiddleware)
    routerParent.Use(authMiddleware)

    router := routerParent.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter();
    router.Use(loggingMiddleware)
    router.Use(errorMiddleware)
    router.Use(authMiddleware)


    // register and login
    {
        handler := routes.LoginHandler{}
        subRouter := router.PathPrefix("/").Subrouter()
        handler.Mount(subRouter, struct{}{});
    }

    {

        handler := routes.RegisterHandler{}
        subRouter := router.PathPrefix("/").Subrouter()
        handler.Mount(subRouter, struct{}{})
    }

    {
        // people
        handler := routes.PersonHandler{}
        subRouter := router.PathPrefix("/").Subrouter()
        subRouter.Use(authMiddleware)
        handler.Mount(subRouter, routes.PersonInjection{People: models.PersonInit()})
    }

     // ...
}
```

none of these get logged:

```
log.Println("error handling middleware registered");
log.Println("auth middleware registered");
log.Println("logging middleware registered");
```

and at runtime none of middleware routes seem to get hit, nothing is logged there. Anyone know why that may be?

Note that I don't expect to need all these:

```
    routerParent := mux.NewRouter()
    routerParent.Use(loggingMiddleware)
    routerParent.Use(errorMiddleware)
    routerParent.Use(authMiddleware)

    router := routerParent.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter();
    router.Use(loggingMiddleware)
    router.Use(errorMiddleware)
    router.Use(authMiddleware)
```

in reality I probably just want:

```
    routerParent := mux.NewRouter()
    router := routerParent.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter();
    router.Use(loggingMiddleware)
    router.Use(errorMiddleware)
    router.Use(authMiddleware)
```

but it's just there to prove that something is off.  At the end of the main func, I have this to start the server:

```
host := os.Getenv("huru_api_host")
port := os.Getenv("huru_api_port")

if host == "" {
    host = "localhost"
}

if port == "" {
    port = "80"
}

log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("Huru API server listening on port %s", port))
path := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", host, port)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(path, routerParent))
```

Comment: While you are waiting for an answer you could debug through it.

Comment: Your main is missing the ListenAndServe part, you first need to hit the router with some requests to see those logs and without a server that isn't gonna happen. Middleware registered with the Use method is applied by the router when a request comes in and a matching handler is found (https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/6137e193cdcba2725f16de84eaf0db2b769d9668/mux.go#L144).

Comment: the server is listening, the routes/handlers respond to requests, but the middleware does appear to be invoked

Comment: I Just tested using your code as base (well except the routes and the ... ) and it works, middlewares are invoked.

Comment: @Nirekin thanks, I just updated the OP to answer your question

Comment: @Nirekin yeah I mean this is just bizarre, I have no idea what's going wrong here

Comment: @AlexanderMills i believe this has to do with the subrouters and it's an unresolved bug (at least i couldn't find anything suggesting a fix) referenced in multiple issues on the project's github repo.

Comment: @AlexanderMills If you try something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/smPiyqFA1dh and as long as your `Mount` methods don't invoke new subrouters you should be fine.

Comment: @mkopriva yeah I am not sure - even this part `routerParent := mux.NewRouter()
 routerParent.Use(loggingMiddleware)
 routerParent.Use(errorMiddleware)
 routerParent.Use(authMiddleware)` doesn't invoke the middleware? That doesn't seem to be a subRouter problem.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to register the middleware? I might have to give up on this methodology. Basically, I want the authMiddleware registered for all but a handful of routes. That's the goal.

Comment: I don't have experience with gorilla mux, however I have tried valyala/fasthttp and gin-gonic/gin . They both provide speedy and functional frameworks for HTTP

Comment: @AlexanderMills Well the middleware just wraps the passed in handler and returns a new handler, so depending on what you're doing in `Mount` you could be able to workaround this problem by applying the middleware to each handler during mount before passing it the router.

Comment: @AlexanderMills if you haven't already try updating gorilla/mux as well, they've made some changes to how subrouters are handled [recently](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/commit/758eb64354aa27cda6c1b026822c788cc755f06f) and from your [issue](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/issues/429) i can see that your version is one commit older. Although I still don't think that that bug has been fixed it might be worth giving it a try.

Comment: I dont think Stackoverflow is the right place to post such questions. Github issues is where you'll find annswers and the contributors, the programmers of the package itself who deal with bugs like these all the time, will always directly respond to you there. Avoid stackoverflow for package/module related too specific questions